# How to create shipment and add tracking number through API in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, shipment, shipment-tracking

I have a csv file with 3 columns with list of (increment_id, carrier_code, tracking_number). How do I Post POST these values to existing magento 2 order using API? I have managed to load the values from csv into a data array and into $incrementid, $carrier, $tracking. i'm new to API, please be detailed as possible.

```
<?php
$file = fopen('track.csv', 'r', '"'); // set path to the CSV file
if ($file !== false)
{
    // add logging capability
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/import-update.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

        public function execute()
        {
        // enter the number of data fields you require the product row inside the CSV file to contain

            $required_data_fields = 3;  //number of column in csv

            while (($row = fgetcsv($this->_file, 100, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                $data_count = count($row);
                if ($data_count < 1) {
                    continue;
                }

                $data = array();
                //$data = array_combine($header, $row);
                $data = array($row);

                $ponumber = $row[0]; //$data['ponumber']; // column A
                if ($data_count < $required_data_fields) {
                    $logger->info("Skipping Order Number " . $ponumber . ". Not enough data to import.");
                    continue;
                }

                $shipvia = isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : null;
                $trackingnumber =  isset($row[2]) ? $row[2] : null;

                switch ($shipvia) {
                    case "FEDEX":
                        $shipvia = "fedex";
                        break;
                    case "UPS":
                        $shipvia = "ups";
                        break;
                    case "USPS":
                        $shipvia = "usps";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $shipvia = "fedex";
                }
            }


    fclose($file); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are shipping all items in the order, there is no need to actually include the items - this is all you need to create a shipment with tracking:

```
{
  "tracks": [
    {
      "track_number": "1Y-9876543210",
      "title": "Custom",
      "carrier_code": "SomeCarrierCode"
    }
  ]
}
```

As long as you have the Magento order ID in the API endpoint `rest/V1/order/{order_id}/ship`, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2 API Shipment tracking you can use **Shipment tracking repository interface**.

> A shipment is a delivery package that contains products. A shipment
>   document accompanies the shipment. This document lists the products
>   and their quantities in the delivery package.

- Method **POST** `/V1/shipment/`

You can pass `orderId` `carrier_code` `tracking_number` in POST **Body Data**

```
{
  "billingAddressId": 0,
  "createdAt": "string",
  "customerId": 0,
  "emailSent": 0,
  "entityId": 0,
  "incrementId": "string",
  "orderId": 0,
  "packages": [
    {
      "extensionAttributes": {}
    }
  ],
  "shipmentStatus": 0,
  "shippingAddressId": 0,
  "shippingLabel": "string",
  "storeId": 0,
  "totalQty": 0,
  "totalWeight": 0,
  "updatedAt": "string",
  "items": [
    {
      "additionalData": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "entityId": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "parentId": 0,
      "price": 0,
      "productId": 0,
      "rowTotal": 0,
      "sku": "string",
      "weight": 0,
      "extensionAttributes": {},
      "orderItemId": 0,
      "qty": 0
    }
  ],
  "tracks": [
    {
      "orderId": 0,
      "createdAt": "string",
      "entityId": 0,
      "parentId": 0,
      "updatedAt": "string",
      "weight": 0,
      "qty": 0,
      "description": "string",
      "extensionAttributes": {},
      "trackNumber": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "carrierCode": "string"
    }
  ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "isCustomerNotified": 0,
      "parentId": 0,
      "extensionAttributes": {},
      "comment": "string",
      "isVisibleOnFront": 0,
      "createdAt": "string",
      "entityId": 0
    }
  ],
  "extensionAttributes": {}
}
```

Comment: can you show a POST example? can i post it with only these 3 information like this: {
  "incrementId": "string",
  "tracks": [
    {
      "trackNumber": "string",
      "carrierCode": "string"
    }
}

Comment: First really sorry for late reply @Kris , all data is exists including { "incrementId": "string", "tracks": [ { "trackNumber": "string", "carrierCode": "string" } } above information

Answer (score 1):

don't know if still needed but you can use the following webservice to add a tracking number to your orders:

**POST: /index.php/rest/V1/shipment/track**

Body

```
{
  "entity": {
    "order_id":     1, this is your order id
    "parent_id":    2, this is the entity_id in DB Table *sales_shipment*
    "track_number": "",
    "carrier_code": ""
  }
}
```

Also don't forget to include in the Header:

- Content-Type: application/json
- Authorization: Bearer "Authorization Key"

Your authorization key can be abtained using this web service

**POST: /index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token**

Body

```
{ "username" : "your_user", "password" : "your_Password" }
```